# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, yii2

when i got upgraded my ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 i have this erro in my yii2 project

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3
of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 
'iicityYii.opportunity_conditions.money' which is not functionally dependent 
on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

The SQL being executed was:

```
SELECT SUM(oc.money),op.id,oc.money,
            op.mantaghe,
            op.`time`, op.`id`, `op`.`logo`,
           `pd`.`user_id`, `op`.`name`, 
           `pd`.`co_name`, `op`.`address`, 
           `op`.`project_type_id`, `op`.`state_id`
FROM `opportunity` op 
INNER JOIN `profile_details` pd  ON op.user_id=pd.user_id  
INNER JOIN `opportunity_conditions` oc ON   op.id=oc.opportunity_id
GROUP BY `op`.`id`
ORDER BY `op`.`id` DESC
```

how to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In select you have an aggregate function named sum and a set of column name, the error tell you that you have not specified the correct list of column name in group by clause. could be you should add more columns name in group by probably related to the `profile_details, opportunity_conditions` table

You have also `,(opportunity.id),(opportunity_conditions.money), (opportunity.mantaghe),`  why the `()` if you need sum you must add sum to all column

```
sum(opportunity.id), sum(opportunity_conditions.money),
```

sum(opportunity.mantaghe),

otherwise if this are normal columns you should use the normal syntax without ()

`opportunity.id, opportunity_conditions.money,opportunity.mantaghe,`

I have tried to rewrite a possible query

```
 SELECT SUM(opportunity_conditions.money),
        `opportunity`.`id`,
        `opportunity_conditions.money`,
        `opportunity.mantaghe`, 
        `opportunity`.`time`, 
        `opportunity`.`logo`, 
        `profile_details`.`user_id`,
        `opportunity`.`name`, 
        `profile_details`.`co_name`,
        `opportunity`.`address`, 
        `opportunity`.`project_type_id`,
        `opportunity`.`state_id` 
FROM `opportunity` 
INNER JOIN `profile_details` ON `opportunity`.`user_id`= `profile_details`.`user_id` 7
INNER JOIN `opportunity_conditions` ON `opportunity`.`id`=`opportunity_conditions`.`opportunity_id` 
GROUP BY`opportunity`.`id`,   `profile_details`.`user_id`,`opportunity_conditions.money`,  
ORDER BY `opportunity`.`id` DESC
```

with group by on the essential column name (i hope)

```
GROUP BY`opportunity`.`id`,   `profile_details`.`user_id`,`opportunity_conditions.money`,
```

Answer (score 116):

Run:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
mysql> SELECT @@global.sql_mode;
```

(Then optionally copy the output to your notes somewhere in case you want to revert to those original settings later.)

And [change the SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting) for your MySQL Server Instance:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

(If you ever want to roll back, you could run something like `mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';` using the value you saved.)

---

A more permanent way (which will survive restarts of MySQL) would be using the MySQL configs. Go to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (or you may need to run `sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf`):

- Add a section for
  `[mysqld]` and right below it add the statement
  `sql_mode = ""` or something like `sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`.
- Restart the MySQL service:

  ```
   sudo systemctl restart mysql
  ```

(or `sudo service mysql restart`)

See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/113153/18098

Comment: How to rollback ?

Answer (score 108):

In laravel with MySql go to file config/database.php and it change in array MySql mode strict to false.

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false, //from true
        'engine' => null,
    ],
],
```

Comment: Even the answer seems valid, I would recommend not to put images of code but the code itself. The OP can then just copy / paste without risk of misspelling during the copy.

Comment: I was super optimistic about this answer, but unfortunately it didn't help me, even if I also ran `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: Actually, suddenly this did start working for me today, so thanks. I'm using WSL 1 with MySQL 8. But I'm not sure that I want to set "strict" to `false` because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42104555/470749

Comment: The perfect solution even now for Laravel 9.x!

Answer (score 18):

The solution is to edit the MySQL config file because the config will revert after every restart...

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

and add

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=""
```

then restart

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Works on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What are security implications of doing something like this?

Comment: Works well on Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 15):

Please just copy this line and run it. it worked for me.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

[Youtube video to fix this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JotQcRT3tuw&t=87s)

Comment: Unfortunately the error returned again, but running the command again fixed it. Not sure why it came back.

Comment: I put for you a youtube link in there please try to visit and watch how to fix

Comment: The youtube video shows how to remove STRICT_ALL_TABLES in phpmyadmin. Removing this and saving did not solve the problem. No change at all. Running SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','')); as a SQL query in phpmyadmin solves the problem temporarily but it comes back automagically by itself after some time.

Comment: I had to also add 
`[mysqld]
sql-mode=""`
to /etc/mysql/my.cnf
Because without that when restarting mysql service issue came back again.

Answer (score 4):

**in laravel**

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'turn.barnamehs.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
select * from `tables` where date(`end_date`) >= 2022-05-10 00:00:00 group by `speciality_id`

> **solution: change 'strict' => false, in config/database.php**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Simply set strict false on following

```
Config > database.php  set 'strict' => false,
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a good idea to update your query to:

```
    SELECT SUM(any_value(oc.money)),op.id,any_value(oc.money) as money,
            op.mantaghe,
            op.`time`, op.`id`, `op`.`logo`,
           any_value(`pd`.`user_id`) as user_id, `op`.`name`, 
           any_value(`pd`.`co_name`) as co_name, `op`.`address`, 
           `op`.`project_type_id`, `op`.`state_id`
FROM `opportunity` op 
INNER JOIN `profile_details` pd  ON op.user_id=pd.user_id  
INNER JOIN `opportunity_conditions` oc ON   op.id=oc.opportunity_id
GROUP BY `op`.`id`
ORDER BY `op`.`id` DESC
```

**Understanding** 
When your query contains `group by` you should only select columns from the table you are grouping by, but if not, you ought to use the `any_value()` function to call the columns from other table.

I personally try not to update the sql_mode global variable.

You can read more about it on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1):

Thx, this helped to me, but this will not set it **PERMANENTLY**, and it will revert after every restart.

So you should set this in your config file (e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf in the [mysqld] section), so that the changes remain in effect after a MySQL restart:

Config File: /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS8 I use webmin config file `/etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-server.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ANY_VALUE` for the non-aggregated columns. So, you could use:

```
SELECT SUM(oc.money),
       op.id,
       ANY_VALUE(oc.money),
       ANY_VALUE(op.mantaghe),
       ANY_VALUE(op.`time`), op.`id`, ANY_VALUE(`op`.`logo`),
       ANY_VALUE(`pd`.`user_id`), ANY_VALUE(`op`.`name`), 
       ANY_VALUE(`pd`.`co_name`), ANY_VALUE(`op`.`address`), 
       ANY_VALUE(`op`.`project_type_id`), ANY_VALUE(`op`.`state_id`)
FROM `opportunity` op 
INNER JOIN `profile_details` pd  ON op.user_id=pd.user_id  
INNER JOIN `opportunity_conditions` oc ON   op.id=oc.opportunity_id
GROUP BY `op`.`id`
ORDER BY `op`.`id` DESC
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578865/439171).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mysql -u root -p

mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Comment: This answer essentially directs you to put duct tape over the `check engine` light.

Answer (score 0):

(Solved) Just include all selected columns in the `Group By` clause, Please have a look at bellow example

Invalid

```
SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)
  FROM orders AS o, customers AS c
  WHERE o.custid = c.custid
  GROUP BY o.custid;
```

Valid (in this query we just include `c.name` also in group by)

```
SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)
  FROM orders AS o, customers AS c
  WHERE o.custid = c.custid
  GROUP BY o.custid,**c.name**;
```

For more information please visit [Main Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

**FOR UBUNTU 22.04LTS**

Open file for editing

`$ sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

then add these lines at the end of file:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```