# how to group by in db query builder to get the unique value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Can someone help me to convert the below mysql to laravel db query builder or eloquent?Here is my mysql

```
SELECT max(created_at), jobseeker_id,call_reason,type_of_call
FROM calllogs
GROUP BY jobseeker_id
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Here is my tries, but no luck yet.

```
             $jobseekers =DB::table('calllogs')
            ->select(DB::raw("max('created_at'),jobseeker_id"))
                 ->groupBy('jobseeker_id')  
                 ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
                 ->get();
                 dd($jobseekers);
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Why 'no luck yet'? You're not specific enough. Laravel's query builder has a `toSql()` method you can use to debug your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$jobseekers =DB::table('calllogs')
  ->select(DB::raw("max(created_at),jobseeker_id"))
  ->groupBy('jobseeker_id')  
  ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
  ->get();
```

Try with this code.
Only delete ' ' in max.
It will work well.

Comment: not yet bro, sorry for late, it show me the error like ss violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'myapp.calllogs.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select max(created_at),jobseeker_id from `calllogs` group by `jobseeker_id` order by `created_at` desc)

Comment: In config/database.php at "mysql" change :
'strict' => true,
to false. Then it will work.

Comment: omg, its worked perfect, can you explain me why? I really thank you so much, i tried it like 1 weeks already.

Comment: Please see this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104412/what-is-the-use-of-strict-in-laravel-config-database

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table(calllogs)
->select(DB::raw('max(created_at) as max_created_at'), 
'jobseeker_id','call_reason','type_of_call')
->groupBy('jobseeker_id')
->orderBy('max_created_at', 'DESC')
->get();   =>As a array.
->first(); => As a object.
```

### Additionally, If you are using table joins see below.

```
->join('table_1','table_1.id','=','table_2.table_1_id')
->leftjoin('table_1','table_1.id','=','table_2.table_1_id')
->rightjoin('table_1','table_1.id','=','table_2.table_1_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'myapp.calllogs.created_at'

Two solution for that error

1.In config/database.php file make sql strict mode to false.

(or)
2. IN groupBy Clause add all your table colums.

example:

->groupBy('jobseeker_id','jobseeker_name','jobseeker_email')

Comment: yeah if i do like this "->groupBy('jobseeker_id','jobseeker_name','jobseeker_email')", it wont give me the unique jobseeker_id,

Comment: post your qurey here