# How to GroupBy in Relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have post table

```
| ID | TITLE | SLUG | CONTENT | COMMENTS_COUNT |
```

and i have post_reactions table

```
| ID | USER_ID | TYPE | POST_ID |
```

I want to make a relationship that what reactions that post have

Comment: i want to know how to apply GroupBy on relationsip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly do it by model.

```
public function postrelation()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PostRelation::class)->groupBy('type');
}
```

Or

```
Post::with(['postrelation' => function($q){
    $q->groupBy('type');
}])->get();
```

Comment: i got this error

message: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '

Comment: In folder config => database.php make sure mysql strict is false, like this

Comment: is it okay to make it false ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104412/what-is-the-use-of-strict-in-laravel-config-database

Comment: is there any option handle it without making it false ?

Comment: I'm not sure about but you've to Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY  `mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));` Run it in mysql

Comment: okay just last thing i have to add count column which count its type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197157/discussion-between-dilip-hirapara-and-rev-tech).

Comment: `->withCount(['postrelation' => function($query) {
  return $query->groupBy('type');
 })`

Comment: please come to chat

Comment: it not solving  with 
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

Comment: Please check https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-turn-off-only-full-group-by.html I hope this will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback function for grouping your relations describe at below.

```
  Post::with(['post_reactions' => function($query){
        $query->groupBy('TYPE');
  }])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make relation with the help of follwing syntax in the Model Class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {

/**
 * Get the phone record associated with the user.
 */
    public function phone(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

Comment: i already have hasMany Relationship my question is how i apply  Groupby on it

Comment: on what basis you want to groupBy?

Comment: by its type column

Comment: You can use this syntax for grouping in Laravel

$array_data = DB::table('post_reactions')
                ->groupBy('TYPE')
                ->having('POST_ID',  1)
                ->get();