# How can I fix this query concat query?

Tags: mysql, laravel

This is what I want to execute, but it does not work:

```
$users = DB::table("users")
->select(array(
  'users.*',
  DB::raw("CONCAT (firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullName "),
))
->where("fullName", "like", $query)
->get();
```

I get this error, as expected:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fullName' in 'where clause'
```

Is there any way to make the where clause aware of fullName? I know I can do this:

```
$users = DB::table("users")
->select(array(
  'users.*',
  DB::raw("CONCAT (firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullName "),
))
->where(DB::raw("CONCAT (firstname, ' ', lastname) like ".$query))
->get();
```

But if I do it like that, then I need to sanitize $query, and I prefer it if the prepared statement deals with it for me as it would in the first example.

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: MySQL allows referencing `SELECT` level aliases in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `HAVING`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `having()` instead of `where()`

```
$users = DB::table("users")
->select(array(
  'users.*',
  DB::raw("CONCAT (firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullName "),
))
->having("fullName", "like", $query)
->get();
```

And change the config setting that check that DB has to run in strict mode:

in `/config/database.php`: do strict to `false`

```
'mysql' => [
        ----
       ----
       'strict' => true,   // <--- Change this to false
       ----
 ],
```

Comment: What are the downsides to changing strict to false?

Comment: Refer this Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104412/what-is-the-use-of-strict-in-laravel-config-database

Answer (score 0):

For that type of information, if you want to get from the Database.
you can use Accessor

```
    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name);
    }
```

Usage:

```
$user = User::find(1);
echo $user->full_name;
```