# Laravel Eloquent - Only one of a kind

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using https://github.com/owen-it/laravel-auditing which logs every change to every model (which uses a special trait) to a table called `audits`:

- `id`
- `auditable_type` = name of the model class which was changed
- `auditable_id` = id of the model which was changed
- `created_at` = date of change
- ...

With the following example data:

```
| id | auditable_type | auditable_id | created_at |
|----|----------------|--------------|------------|
| 1  | App\City       | 1            | 2019-01-01 |
| 2  | App\City       | 2            | 2019-01-02 |
| 3  | App\City       | 2            | 2019-01-02 |
```

Now I wanna query the two latest changes (`order by created_at DESC`) of all models, which is pretty easy:

```
Audit::query()
    ->limit(2)
    ->orderBy("created_at", "DESC")
    ->get()
```

Which will result to this:

```
| id | auditable_type | auditable_id | created_at |
|----|----------------|--------------|------------|
| 2  | App\City       | 2            | 2019-01-02 |
| 3  | App\City       | 2            | 2019-01-02 |
```

But how to get the latest changed model rows, not the latest changes:

```
| id | auditable_type | auditable_id | created_at |
|----|----------------|--------------|------------|
| 1  | App\City       | 1            | 2019-01-01 |
| 3  | App\City       | 2            | 2019-01-02 |
```

Normally, I would use GroupBy, but thats not possible (directly) on eloquent models, right?

Comment: You can use groupBy with the query builder...  `groupBy('auditable_type', 'auditable_id')`

Comment: Yes, you can use `groupBy` on a collection. as shown in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby). You can also `groupBy` on a query builder as shown [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).

Comment: did your db server supports window functions?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_window_function

Comment: @devon and @swonder: That was my first guess, but then I get the `this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` error.

Comment: @michail1982: nope. MySQL 5.7

Comment: Ah.. I now found the solution. Just use group by and disable strict mode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50393074/1006818

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
public function latest($column = 'created_at')
{
    return $this->orderBy($column, 'desc');
} 
Audit::->latest()->take(2)->get();
```

Comment: `take` is just an alias of `limit`, so it will not change anything.

Comment: are you try to use latest() function?

Comment: Check my updated post,I hope this solution help you.