# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and

Tags: laravel

I disable "only_full_group_by" on mysql but "laravel" giving above error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'answer_reactions.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `answer_reactions` where `answer_reactions`.`answer_id` in (147, 156, 165) group by `answer_reactions`.`type`)
```

Comment: how did you disable it ? in database.php strict ? anyway, i dont recommend you to do so. you should explain more what you are trying to get as a result and we will help you with it, especially with strict mode active.

Comment: The following question and its answers are better than those on this page. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41145619/470749

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in Laravel `config\database.php` file, inside the `mysql` driver array add `'strict' => false,` and give it a try.

Comment: i dont want to make it false

Answer (score 0):

Test with:

```
GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Comment: Explain where the user went wrong and try to explain how this solves the issue